# Passing boolean instead of Boolean in grails

Tags: grails, types, parameters, arguments, boolean

I am trying to pass a little-b `boolean` as an argument in this call:

```
boolean f = false
DiskFileItem fileItem = diskFileItemFactory.createItem('file',  
   'multipart/file-upload', f as boolean, file.name)
```

But I get the exception:

```
No signature of method: static DiskFileItemFactory.createItem()
  is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, 
  java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.String) values: [file, multipart/file-upload, false,
  file.txt] Possible solutions: createItem(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, 
  boolean, java.lang.String)
```

Looks like it is still passing the big-b Boolean object rather than the primitive.  Is there a way I can force the primitive rather than the wrapper class as an argument (or is that completely not the error)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `f.booleanValue()` will work?